# Content Replacement not in hyperlinks

Tags: php

I have a simple function that all content on my website is filtered through to capitilize the company's name. Here is the function:

```
function brand_capitilize($content) {
    $content = str_replace("Brand", "BRAND", $content);
    return $content;
}
```

I need to modify this to ignore the word "Brand" if it's in a url. For example, I do not want the word 'Brand' to be capitalized in the following situation:

```
<a href="http://mycompany.com/files/Brand.pdf">View PDF</a>
```

If I feed this through brand_capitilize() right now, I end up with:

```
<a href="http://mycompany.com/files/BRAND.pdf">View PDF</a>
```

Comment: If EVERY Content on your website has to go through that function, you got another problem than the url of links to files.

Comment: Of course you could do that with an preg_replace. But that's even more overload if you use it on all your website.